# jQuery parseJSON behaving differently in two domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a cPanel server with two domains. Note that both servers are on the same "machine" (they are just different domains). One is a domain for testing the code in the server and the other is the production server. At a given point of my code I have the following:

```
console.log(data);
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data);
```

My **TEST** domain produces the following: (focus on `"birth":"1992-07-30"`)

```
"message":"","code":"","response":{"id":"1","name":"Andr\u00e9","news":"1","birth":"1992-07-30","email":[{"id":"27","email":"teste@gmail.com","accountId":"1"}]},"field":false,"exception":false}
```

After the parse

[image]

Now my **PRODUCTION DOMAIN** gives me the following: (focus on `"birth":"1992-07-30"`)

```
{"message":"","code":"","response":{"id":"1","name":"Andr\u00e9","news":"1","birth":"1992-07-30","email":[{"id":"1","email":"teste@gmail.com","accountId":"1"}]},"field":false,"exception":false}
```

After the parse

[image]

Recaping:

- 1 Machine; 2 Domains; 2 FTPs; 2 Databases;
- Same jQuery Library;
- Since I manually uploaded some files, I'm not sure if they're on the same "revision/build", but considering that the problem lies only in jQuery, I feel like my own code before and after those three lines is completely irrelevant.

How can this happen?

---

Edit: In order to give a little bit more information, here is the whole function. It is a callback function set to the jQuery.ajax() function. **The relevant code is at line 4~6**.

```
    success: function(data) {
    try {
        if (data != '') {
            console.log(data);
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            if (data.message && data.message != '') {
                if (data.field) {
                    Nav.ajax.focus(data.field, resource);
                    Nav.alert(data.message, null, 1);
                } else {
                    if (data.exception)
                        Nav.alert(data.message, null, 2);
                    else
                        Nav.alert(data.message, null, 0);
                }

            }

            if (data.response != null && callback) {
                callback(data.response);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
    Nav.ajax.screen('finish');
}
```

Comment: Is the "log -> parse -> log" procedure being called asynchronously, such that the "data" variable is also accessible to some other code, which could change it during those three calls? Otherwise I don't know how your issue is possible.

Comment: I don't think so, although my javascript knowledge is a little bit limited, I could be sure it's a procedural function. I'm going to edit the main post to present with the full function.

Comment: Well, the odd thing is that the browser console is reporting that the value is a STRING (I would have expected some whiz-bang-unknown-auto-date-making feature of jquery's parseJSON to have made the element a DATE, but that value is clearly a string).  So I reckon that you looked at the wrong response from the server, and the server is set to give you the date in a different default format.

Comment: I got tired yesterday and I went to sleep. Today when I woke up, I logged into the Production system and tested the code, it was working fine.